# Flatten a list two ways: (i) using MAPCAN and (ii) using LOOP

Tags: common-lisp

My professor has given us a refresher assignment in clisp.  One exercise is to achieve the same thing in three ways: Return a flattened list of all positive integers in a given list.

Now, there's only one way I *really* like doing this, using cons and recursion, but he wants me to do this using mapcan and a loop (I suspect lisp is not his first choice of language because this style of coding feels extremely resistant to the nature of lisp).  I'm having a hard time working out how one would do this using a loop...I need to first start a list, I suppose?

I apologize for vague language as I'm not really sure how to TALK about using a functional language to write procedurally.  Following is my first attempt.

```
(defun posint-loop (l)  
  (loop for i in l
        do (if (listp i)  
               (posint-loop i)  
               (if (integerp i)  
                   (if (> i 0)  
                       (append i) ; this doesn't work because there's nothing to
                                  ; start appending to!
                       nil)  
                   nil))))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show how you would _like_ to do it.

Comment: I would also like to put forward the thought that _you_ might be the one who has not understood the nature of Lisp, instead of your professor. :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to establish a new lexical binding, use [`let`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/speope_letcm_letst.html) or the [`with`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_abb.htm) keyword of [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_a.htm).  In order to extend an existing list, you might want to use [`push`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/mac_push.html); if you need the original order, you can [`nreverse`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_reversecm_nreverse.html) the new list [`finally`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_agb.htm).

Another way would be to use the [`when`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_af.htm) and [`collect`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_ac.htm) keywords of [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/06_a.htm).

Another hint:  [`mapcan`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_mapccm_ma_istcm_mapcon.html) implicitly creates a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Mapcan applies a function to each element of a list, expecting the function to return a list, and then concatenates those resulting lists together.  To apply it to this problem, you just need to process each element of the toplevel list.  If the element is a list, then you need to process it recursively.  If it's not, then you either need to return an empty list (which will add no elements to the final result) or a list of just that element (which will add just that element to the final result):

```
(defun flatten2 (list)
  (mapcan (lambda (x)
            (cond
             ((listp x) (flatten2 x))
             ((and (integerp x) (plusp x)) (list x))
             (t '())))
          list))
```

```
(flatten2 '((a 1 -4) (3 5 c) 42 0))
;=> (1 3 5 42)
```

With loop, you can do just about the same thing with the recognition that **(mapcan f list)** is functionally equivalent to **(loop for x in list nconc (funcall f x))**.  With that in mind, we have:

```
(defun flatten3 (list)
  (loop for x in list
        nconc (cond 
               ((listp x) (flatten3 x))
               ((and (integerp x) (plusp x)) (list x))
               (t '()))))
```